# how can i acces to balance in the 'byUSer' list user in this dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

## Deseo accesar al segundo balance

data = {
        'totalRecords' : 'total_de_movimientos',
        'totalCredit' : 'suma_del_credito',
        'totalDebit' : 'suma_del_debito',
        'balance' : 'resultado_credito_menos_debito',
        'byUser' : [ #Aqui van todos los registros de los empleados...
            {
                'name' : 'nombre_del_usuario',
                'uid' : 'uid_del_usuario',
                'records' : 'total_de_movimientos_del_usuario',
                'resumen' : {
                    'credit' : 'suma_del_credit_de_este_usuario',
                    'debit' : 'suma_del_debit_de_este_usuario',
                    'balance' : 'resultado_credito_menos_debito_usuario'
                }
            }
        ]
     }

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please see [ask]

Comment: just want to read the 'balance' key in this dict

Comment: `my_dict['balance']`?

Comment: Look, it's easier if you show us what you've tried and how it failed.

Comment: SO sorry man, I dont know use this

Comment: no, balance is in an list in a dict place, see

Comment: So there are two keys `balance` in your example data and you want the second (?). Please [edit] your question. Just the title and some clarification in comments do not help us help you.

Comment: @EdgarOcampo ok, then index into that key in the outer dict, then into the list, then into the *other dict*... What exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: it was answered tanks, I just wanna acces to the 2nd balance key

Comment: You can still [edit] your question for clarity (that link [edit] opens the editor right away, that's why I provided it). Being a new member of Stack Overflow I recommend you read that link in the first comment. You may want to know that if you have a continuous streak of badly received questions, you may be not be able to ask new questions for a while, or for ever.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you question correctly, you are trying to access 'balance' from the variable 'data'. This is a simple case of accessing values in a nested dictionary (complicated by the fact that one of the values happen to be a list). You can use the below

`data['byUser'][0]['resumen']['balance']`